# How to stop door knob latch from twisting and sticking on strike plate?

Tags: doors, lock

The latches on a couple of doors around the house have started twisting when they are turned. Sometimes this causes the latch to get stuck on the strike plate, meaning the door doesn't close properly. This is what it looks like when the latch gets stuck:

[image: door latch caught on strike plate]

[This is what it looks like when the handle is twisted.](https://youtu.be/CLNSyK46Tmc)

How can I stop this? Is there a way other than buying completely new door knobs? I've taken a lock from another door which has this same problem off and I can't see anything that is obviously wrong.

If it's any help these are basic 'button' door locks. No key, just a push button on one side that locks it from the other.

Comment: Time for new locks; these are worn out. This design invites twisting like this; the front edge of the bolt plate is circular not rectangular.

Comment: @JimStewart Stewart Don't know why I didn't expect that answer, since they'd probably be >10 years old at this point. Thanks.

Comment: I am supposing that the brand of these locks in ordinary builder type, and not some special "designer" model that is actually valuable despite having a  mechanical design flaw. I can't read the manufacturer's name on the plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locks appear to be worn out. If these are just inexpensive builder's grade door locks, replace them.

You then get to decide whether you want knobs or lever handles. We opted for levers and these have worked well for the bedroom and bathroom doors because they are recessed from the hallway. We also used a lever handle on the HVAC closet in the hallway which was a mistake because it is flush with the wall and is an interference.